# How to set DefaultValue of Sort Parameter on an ObjectDataSource

Tags: asp.net, gridview, objectdatasource

I have a GridView with `AllowSorting="True"`, and I have an ObjectDataSource with `SortParameterName="orderBy"` ,`SelectMethod="GetScheduledSurveys"` and

```
<SelectParameters>
<asp:Parameter Name="orderBy" Type="String" DefaultValue="SurveyDueDate" />
</SelectParameters>
```

When I first go to the page, the DefaultValue for the "orderBy" SelectParameter is not passed to the "GetScheduledSurveys" SelectMethod. It is only passed in when I click on a heading in the GridView. How do I get it to use the default on first access?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a reason why you don't have this data sorted before you pass it to your datasource (i.e. sort it on your stored procedure, or query)? If not I would suggest to do it on `Page_Load` when `Page.IsPostBack==false`. Good luck!

Comment: There isn't and just after I posted the question I added if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(orderBy))                orderBy = "SurveyDueDate"; into my "GetScheduledSurveys" SelectMethod. It's just that I'm surprised that the DefaultValue wasn't passed in and I wondered if there was something I should do in the aspx.

Comment: @Hanlet Escaño I, too, am now facing this problem. I have a default sorting field declared in my SelectMethod, but the SelectMethod is a method I reuse throughout with many different datasources. Sometimes my datasources have different requirements for sorting, depending on my page logic. Isn't there a way to force the datasource to pass the sort parameter? I'd rather not have to do it manually in `Page_Load` using `Control.DataBind()`.